# Multiples form request Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to build form to perform multiples request. 
Here is an example of what i want to do
[image]

In this case SQL request should be something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE city = city1 or city = city2 or pet = pet2 or pet = pet3 or food = food1
```

I tried to do it with symfony with no success because "symfony except string not array"

```
   class CoreSearchType extends AbstractType
    {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('city' , ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' =>array('France' => $this->getChoicesCities()),
                'label' => false,'required' => true,'placeholder'=>'Choose','multiple' => true])
```

But i dont know what how to do it. 
If someone can help me finding the way to do it ...
Please Notice that i use symfony 4

edit : I want to be able to choose two cities (or more), for exemple : city1 and city2 (all the city1 sample + the city2 sample, and not a variable type-hinted city1 and city2)

for exemple if : 
city1 = paris, tokyo, rio 
city2= amiens, madrid, london

the answer of the request will be : paris,tokyo,rio,amiens,madrid,london

Thanks !

Comment: What does `$this->getChoicesCities()` return exactly?

Comment: its private method who call the entiy where cities are stock

Comment: Can you share the code of this method?

Comment: with pleasure     private function getChoicesCities()
    {

        $mizecore = Core::ARRON;
        $output = [];
        foreach (Core::ARRON as $key => $value)
        {
            $output[$value] = $key;
        }
        return $output;
    }

Comment: thanks you a lot for your support

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in your question you want a form which consists of three choice types. Here is an example on how this could look like.

```
class CoreSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) 
    {
        $builder
            ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'city 1' => 'city1',
                    'city 2' => 'city2',
                    'city 3' => 'city3',
                ],
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose',
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
            ->add('pet', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'pet 1' => 'pet1',
                    'pet 2' => 'pet2',
                    'pet 3' => 'pet3',
                ],
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose',
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
            ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'food 1' => 'food1',
                    'food 2' => 'food2',
                    'food 3' => 'food3',
                ],
                'label' => false,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose',
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

Please check the part regarding the `choices` option in the symfony docs here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

> The `choices` option is an array, where the array key is the item's label and the array value is the item's value

I think your error might come from this line:

```
'choices' => array('France' => $this->getChoicesCities())
```

It might work if you change it to

```
'choices' => array($this->getChoicesCities())
```

Comment: Hello ! A huge thanks you for your help. Unfortunatly i still get the same error

Comment: Expected argument of type "string", "array" given at property path "city".

Comment: edit : I want to be able to choose two cities, for exemple : city1 and city2 (all the city1 sample + the city2 sample, and not a variable type-hinted city1 and city2)

Comment: Can you please share the code of your method `getChoicesCities()` or at least an example for its return value?